# Question about the temporary COVID-19 provisions in the EU on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I live in Romania, where the government deals with COVID-19 by passing temporary **laws**. My questions however, is with regards to the EU as a whole and any convention that may apply to cross-boarder travel during the COVID-19 pandemic. So it might be a **law** question on topic for this site. My second choice is travel.SE.

Specifically, I have to travel from Romania to the Netherlands over land (by car), which involves 4 boarder crossings. My question would explain why I believe my reasons count as "urgency" and documentation I intend to produce for relevant authorities.

The question comes down to: "Am I allowed to travel from Romania to the Netherlands?"

Comment: It depends on whether you want a practical answer, or are you interested in what the law is. I doubt that there is a clear answer based on law, instead you need a travel-experience based answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be on topic here but you might do better at travel.

Comment: I'll try my luck at travel then.